# Is there any way to get a list of members only videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am a member of the channel I want to query the members only video. Is there any way to get a list of members only videos from a channel?

I've tried activities and search APIs but they don't include members only videos in the response, and I am doing this with OAuth2.

Is there any way for this or this wouldn't be possible?

## What i have tried

Here's an example members only video I'm a members to: youtube.com/watch?v=vYmAhoZYg64

Here's the result of search.list with curl command

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC1DCedRgGHBdm81E1llLhOQ&publishedAfter=2020-10-03T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2020-10-05T00%3A00%3A00Z&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \   
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \   
--header 'Accept: application/json' \   
--compressed pastebin.pl/view/49bb1fe9
```

[results](https://pastebin.pl/view/49bb1fe9)

Comment: There are videos that only visible if you are a member of a channel. I've checked the docs and it only has how to list members of a channel.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/membershipsLevels

Comment: Have you checked https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#usage

It seems it only able to list my subscription?

Comment: Yeah thats how it works its the current users subscriptions, you cant see what someone else has subscribed to with out there permission that's private user data.

Comment: How is that relevant to my question? I am a member of the channel I want to query the members only video.

Comment: I have edited your question so that it is now clear what you are asking.   Have you tried using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list and adding the channel id?   While you are at it please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: I still haven't write any code yet until I got all the information I needed. Currently I am still wandering around https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs API explorer if it's possible to get members only video through the API. I've Googled a bit and it's probably currently impossible to do so, but I want to know if I am wrong or not.

Comment: Did you try search.list is it returning there?  If not i would add it as a feature request.

Comment: Here's an example members only video I'm a members to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYmAhoZYg64

Here's the result of search.list with curl command `curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC1DCedRgGHBdm81E1llLhOQ&publishedAfter=2020-10-03T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2020-10-05T00%3A00%3A00Z&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed`

https://pastebin.pl/view/49bb1fe9

Comment: Have you considered submitting a feature request?   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803

Comment: ok, so it is true that this is currently impossible then. Alright I'll fill a feature request as per your suggestion. In the meantime, maybe I should scrape the channel's Community Posts for this to work. Thank you, maybe you can answer with a "Not possible" post and I'll accept it as answer..

Answer (score 0):

Via API, I don't think there is a way (yet).

But you can use external tools to scrape this information.

For example, using yt-dlp:

```
yt-dlp {channel_URL} --flat-playlist --print title,url --cookies-from-browser chrome
```

(You can include your cookies/credentials in other ways, of course.)